# Check Style Report Weird Indent issue

Tags: java, indentation, checkstyle

Checkstyle complains the incorrect indentation only for below piece of code. I tries to format the code by intellij or manually but none of them worked. And when I fixed the issue by the error messasge, the indentation level is still incorrect but the number changed.

```
        Map<MessageStatusAndErrorCode, Integer> result = MESSAGES_POLLER_EXECUTOR_SERVICE.invokeAll(callables).stream()
                .map(stringFuture -> {
                    try {
                        return stringFuture.get();
                    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
                    } 
                })
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), reducing(0, e -> 1, Integer::sum)));
        messagesStatusCountMap.putAll(result);
```

The error message from checkstyle:

```
'try' have incorrect indentation level 20, expected level should be 24.
Line 132'try' child have incorrect indentation level 24, expected level should be 28.
Line 133'try rcurly' have incorrect indentation level 20, expected level should be 24.
Line 134'catch' child have incorrect indentation level 24, expected level should be 28.
Line 135'block rcurly' have incorrect indentation level 22, expected level should be 20.
Line 135'catch rcurly' have incorrect indentation level 20, expected level should be 24.
```

Comment: Move that `try-catch` logic to a `static` method and call the static method instead?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch can you add more explanation?